# What is the difference between these two decorators that are seemingly doing the same?

Tags: python, python-decorators

So here's a common decorator:

Example #1:

```
def decorator(or_func):

    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        print(f'ran before {or_func.__name__} function')
        return or_func(*args, **kwargs)
    
    return wrapper

@decorator
def displayy(id, id2):
    print(f'display is running with the id {id} and {id2}')

displayy(8, 17)
```

So as a self taught developer I try to come up with new ways of doing stuff (usually stupid ideas), and then make some sort of pros and cons. So I came up with this:

Example #2:

```
def decorator(or_func):
    print(f'ran before {or_func.__name__} function')
    return or_func

@decorator
def displayy(id, id2):
    print(f'display is running with the id {id} and {id2}')

displayy(8, 17)
```

In my mind when I wrote this I expected an error because I actually didn't pass in the required arguments to `or_func`. but actually it worked the same!.

You see when I came up with example 2 I thought the pros was "It's shorter" but in return "it can't take in any arguments" I assume this because the first layer of function in decorators takes in the original function as an argument. So that's why we return a wrapper function in my example 1, to take in the arguments. But now I'm confused.

So my questions are

1. Why is it better to use example #1 instead?
2. What are the things that example #1 can do that example #2 can't do?
3. how is the `displayy` function is able to take in the right argument despite me not passing `(*args, **kwargs)`?

Comment: You need to change your experiment to be certain of what is happening. You should add: `print('Before call to displayy')` just before `displayy(8, 17)`. Perhaps also add another call like: `displayy(9, 42)`.

Comment: In the first example you need to pass `(*args, **kwargs)` because the function you are returning that "pretends to be" the decorated function is the wrapper. So you need to take the arguments wrapper gets and pass them to the decorated function. In the 2nd example you are returning the original function unchanged, so it behaves just like it would without decorator.

Comment: Decorator syntax is just syntactic sugar for function application. `displayy` is defined, then the assignment `displayy = decorator(displayy)` is performed. That's it. There's no magic semantics involved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They're not doing the same. In the second example `print(f'ran before {or_func.__name__} function')` only gets called while you're decorating the function, not when you run the "decorated" function after that. You didn't actually change the function, it's the same as

```
print(f'ran before {or_func.__name__} function')

def displayy(id, id2):

    print(f'display is running with the id {id} and {id2}')
```

In the second example try running `display` a second time to see what I mean.